# How many keywords or reserved words in MVEL

Tags: mvel

How many keywords or reserved words in MVEL, can anyone list them out? I did not find out in the official documentation of MVEL, really appreciate any helps your can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be new additions and deletions based on the version you are using

But according [to this doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mvel/mvel/2.0-dp4/org/mvel/compiler/AbstractParser.java?av=f),this is the function used to check if the specified string is a reserved word in the parser.

```
public static boolean  isReservedWord(String name) {    
       return LITERALS.containsKey(name) || OPERATORS.containsKey(name);
    }
```

Where

**Literals Map contains**

```
true,Array,Boolean,boolean,char,Character,Class,ClassLoader,Compiler,Double,double,empty,false,Float,float,int,Integer,Long,long,Math,nil,null,Object,Runtime,SecurityManager,Short,short,StrictMath,String,StringBuffer,StringBuilder,System,Thread,ThreadLocal,Void
```

**Operators List**

```
if,-,--,!=,#,%,&,&&,*,**,/,:,;,?,^,|,||,~=,+,++,+=,<,<<,<<<,<=,=,-=,==,>,>=,>>,>>>,and,assert,contains,convertable_to,def,do,else,for,foreach,function,import,import_static,in,instanceof,is,new,or,return,soundslike,strsim,switch,var,while,with
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use this method, it has now been moved to `org.mvel2.util.ParseTools.java` for mvel2.